# How can I tell whether a process is running with administrator permissions?

Tags: windows-vista, uac, privileges

I'm using Windows Vista, with UAC enabled. I've installed an application, and the installer required admin privileges. The installer then started the application. I'd like to know if the application is continuing to run with admin privileges.

I've tried Windows Task Manager and Process Explorer, and neither appear to show this information.

Comment: For updated OS please see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1213101/check-if-an-app-is-running-as-admin). Task Manager Details tab has an optional Elevated column.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), double click the process to open its properties.  Go to the **Security** tab.  In the group listing, find **BUILTIN\Administrators** and look at what it says in the **Flags** column.

Deny = Not Elevated (not admin)

[image]

Owner = Elevated (is admin)

[image]

Comment: On my Windows 7 system, I had to run *Process Explorer* with elevated permissions in order to be able to see certain details (such as the Security permissions) of processes running with administrator permissions. When running *Process Explorer* as a regular user, the contents of the Security tab were blank.

Comment: Nothing like this at all existing in Win10; use sysinternals (@Tim), add "integrity level" to columns for processes.

Comment: Win8 and higher have always had an optional column in Task Manager named **Elevated** that displays yes or no. This is in the Details tab of course.

Answer (score 52):

In Process Explorer you can change the columns displayed and add the "Integrity level" column from the "Process Image" tab:

[image]

This is apparently the technical term for what is changed when you run a process with administrator privileges. If you run Process Explorer as an Administrator it will show ordinary processes as 'medium' integrity level and elevated processes as 'high'.

Note that if you run process explorer as an ordinary user, it will show processes that have admin privileges with a blank entry in the integrity level column.

Comment: Also when running a specific program as an administrator and process explorer as normal user, process explorer won't display the process's true icon, but a blank icon.

Answer (score 3):

Update with the OSes: Resource Monitor, which I believe is included with Windows 7 and Windows 10 (not sure about Vista) has an optional 'Elevated' column on the CPU tab's list of processes section that seems to be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use command-line tools, the [Accesschk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) utility from the [MS Sysinternals suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) can be used to check if a process is running with administrator permissions.

The following flags are useful for this purpose:

- The `-p` (process) option accepts either the name or PID of a running process.
- The `-v` (verbose) option prints the [Windows Integrity Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx)
- The `-q` (quiet) option prevents version information from being printed.
- The `-f` (full) option can also be used to provide even more information on the process(es) (security token details of users, groups and privileges) but this level of additional details is not required to check for elevated privileges.

#### Example

List the privileges of the all the running `cmd` processes:

```
> accesschk.exe -vqp cmd

[5576] cmd.exe
  Medium Mandatory Level [No-Write-Up, No-Read-Up]
  RW ICS\Anthony
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
[8224] cmd.exe
  Medium Mandatory Level [No-Write-Up, No-Read-Up]
  RW ICS\Anthony
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
Error opening [6636] cmd.exe:
Access is denied.
```

Here, we can see that there are three `cmd` processes that I started. The first two have a *Medium* Mandatory (Integrity) Level and are shown as running under my domain account, indicating that these processes were started without administrator privileges.

However, the last process (PID 6636) was started with elevated permissions so my non-privileged command can’t read information about that process. Running with elevated permissions `accesschk` and explicitly specifying its PID prints the following information:

```
> accesschk.exe -vqp 6636

[6636] cmd.exe
  High Mandatory Level [No-Write-Up, No-Read-Up]
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
```

Now we can see that the Integrity Level is *High* and that this process is running under the `Administrators` built-in security group.