# Windows Task Manager: How to see elevation status?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, elevation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell whether a process is running with administrator permissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/74447/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-process-is-running-with-administrator-permissions)

Windows 7 Task Manager, Processes tab.

When I run a programm, batch ... elevated (run as Administrator), I still see it with my User name "HorstWalter" in the Windows Task Manager.

I'd have expected to see it as user name "Administrator". However, how can I tell the process is running elevated?

Comment: @HorstWalter, If you know the answer now, you can just close the question yourself.

Comment: I just wanted to give BloodPhilia the chance to get the credits (points)

Comment: @HorstWalter Even though appreciated, it would be undeserved credit because it would be copying the answers on the other questions. Please just close the question as a duplicate of the one I supplied. Click the "Close" link at the bottom of your question and mark it as a duplicate. Happy SUing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this from inside Task Manager. You can however use SysInternal's Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) program which is effectively Task Manager on steroids.

Comment: Here is how exactly it can be done: http://superuser.com/a/74471/72397