# Check if an app is running as admin

Tags: windows-10, privileges, application-launch

How can I check in Windows if application is launched with administrative privileges? I see no corresponding column in Task Manager.

Comment: [How to See if Process is running as administrator (elevated) in Vista and Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/319748-process-see-if-running-administrator-elevated.html) should work in Windows 10.

Answer (score 25):

**To check whether processes are running as elevated in Windows 10 do the following:**

1. Open **Task Manager**
2. Go to the **Details** tab
3. Hover your mouse somewhere in the thin horizontal bar at the top of the **Details** window pane where the columns are labeled (such as **Name**, **PID**, **Status**, **User name**, etc..)
4. Right-click your mouse and choose **Select Columns**.
5. In the new window that opens up scroll down towards the bottom and you'll see an unselected check box labeled **Elevated**. Check that box and click OK to close that window.
6. Now your **Details** tab of **Task Manager** will be showing a new **Elevated** column. Look for an app that is launched and check to see if it is running with Elevated Privileges.
   [image]